# Adding replacement strings to a list

Tags: list, dabbrev

I want to add replacements to matching words to a list called `nscrip`.

I already have a large number of lists that I use for dabbrev, written in the following form.  Perhaps I can use these lists, or else have two lists (one for matching and one for replacement strings) if the latter would work better.

```
(defconst ptc-tablet-16
  '( ("almost" "lmo")    ("beautiful" "btf")  ("big" "bg")
     ("bird" "b/")       ("brother" "Bro")    ("child" "ci")
     ("children" "cil")  ("dear" "de")        ("feel" "fl") ))
```

Without a list I am using the following expression

```
(add-to-list 'nscrip (s-replace-regexp "almost" "lmo" word))
```

Comment: This question is seriously about the kind of list? Or you are trying to ask about something else? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I could have the structure as shown, in the form used by `dabbrev`.  Or perhaps using two lists would work better, but I am not sure about what approach would work best.  I then need a way to use the chosen list to loop through and add the replacements to another list.

Comment: Personally, I would use conses for the 'pairs', because I would not need to type an extra `car` to get the latter word. But you might prefer to type one extra `car` instead of typing multiple dots. Otherwise, I would say that an alist is a perfect candidate here. Please read about `alist-get`, and its docstring to see how to make it match on strings, before you ask a new question here.

Comment: I have done  `(setq mylist '(("pine" . "cones") ("oak" . "acorns") ("maple" . "seeds")))`.  Then I could do  `(assoc "pine" mylist)`.  And in general  `(assoc word mylist)`.

Comment: Fine, `alist-get` would add the `cdr` for you. On the other hand, `assoc` already matches on strings...

Comment: The replacement would then be  `(cdr (assoc word mylist))`.  Correct?

Comment: How would I loop through the `alist` when using the command  `(add-to-list 'protocuneus-nscrip (s-replace-regexp car-elem (cdr (assoc car-elem mylist)) word))`?

Comment: I am thinking that instead of looping I can do `(add-to-list 'nscrip (s-replace-regexp word (cdr (assoc word mylist) word))`.

Comment: Think about what you need the loop for? Trying to get an element from the alist? Is this functionality already provided by some other function you already know/are using? Then, indeed, use that. In general, I would suggest that when writing functions, you first write down only comments describing the steps that are required... then fill in the steps to implement the function. If then you have a question, post the comments/steps, with the code you have...

Comment: That's good advice.  Thank you so very much for that.  I have some code now.

Answer (score 0):

I have come up this solution.  I am not quite sure how efficient this is.

```lisp
    (defconst alist-tablet-1
      '( ("all" . "l")     ("as" . "as")      ("can" . "k")
         ("do" . "do")     ("for" . "f")      ("in" . "n")
         ("is" . "s")      ("it" . "t")       ("know" . "no")
         ("like" . "lk")   ("little" . "ll")  ("more" . "mo")
         ("other" . "O")   ("some" . "so")    ("than" . "n")
         ("that" . "ta")   ("there" . "tr")   ("this" . "th")
         ("time" . "ti")   ("to" . "to")      ("we" . "w")
         ("well" . "l")    ("will" . "l")     ("work" . "wk")
         ("you" . "u") ))
    
    (defun shorten-word ()
      "Shorten word at point using alist-tablet-1."
    
      (interactive)
    
      (let* ( (bounds  (bounds-of-thing-at-point 'word))
              (word    (buffer-substring (car bounds) (cdr bounds))) )
    
        (goto-char (car bounds))
    
        (add-to-list 'nscrip
           (s-replace-regexp word (cdr (assoc word alist-tablet-1)) word))))
```

Comment: Do you have the original format lists already?

Comment: Original lists were of the form used by abbrev, one shown in the question.

Comment: So there's no point in converting those lists by hand, you can use them as is.  Just do `(cadr x)` instead of `(cdr x)`  that would be: `(cadr (assoc word alist-tablet-1))`

Comment: @dalanicolai was of the opinion that alist is a perfect candidate here.  You can put another answer, and we can all discuss it.

Comment: The lists were not really suitable for `abbrev` because customarily `abbrev` is used to convert an abbreviation to a longer phrase.  But I am doing the other way round, changing a word to an abbreviation.  Furthermore, abbrev cannot handle punctuation in the strings.

Comment: .... use alists.

Comment: We all approve of alists then.

Comment: You could use just `backward-word`. And although using external libraries is fine, I would prefer to use the standard function `replace-regexp-in-string`. But anyway... looks good!

Comment: External libraries because I am using `s.el`?  Perhaps I do not need to replace anything.  All I need is to check if word matches `car` of `alist` element, then put `cdr` in `nscrip` list.

Comment: I have actually encountered a problem when word does not exist in `alist-tablet-1`.  I get `Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function nil)  nil(#("owell" 0 5 (fontified t))) replace-regexp-in-string(#("owell" 0 5 (fontified t)) nil #("owell" 0 5 (fontified t))) (add-to-list 'nscrip`